# L is not defined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Al usar leaflet en mi index, lo hago de manera correcta y no tengo problemas. Pero, en otro html del sitio, que lo tengo vinculado con el mismo main.js, me da dicho error y no me deja ejecutar otras funciones. La línea del error en main.js es:

```js
var map = L.map('mapa').setView([-31.89415, -61.84540], 16);
```

¿A qué puede deberse si en el index donde tengo el mapa no me da problemas? En cada html el sitio debo referenciar los css y script de leaflet por mas que no use mapas??

Para los que me preguntan, definí dentro del body el script de leaflet. Y como creo que el error esta en el main.js les dejo como lo tengo hecho.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      
      var map = L.map('mapa').setView([-31.89415, -61.84540], 16);
      

      L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map);
      
      L.marker([-31.89415, -61.84540]).addTo(map)
          .bindPopup('Hogar del Lic Mendoza J.C')
          .openPopup();
```

Importación de leaflet.js y main.js:

```
<script src="unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script> 
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás colocando ese código? ¿Antes o después del `body`? En lo posible, procurá mostrar un [repro]. Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿En qué orden estás importando leaflet y main.js? ¿En el orden en que lo mencioné o primero el main.js y luego leaflet?

Comment: <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
Pero, sigo con la duda, en todos los html tengo que poner  el script de leaflet, o solo donde necesito visualizar mapas??

Comment: Julio César... ¿No será que te falta el https:// en la URL? ;)

Comment: Lo tiene, solo que no salió publicado.

Comment: la variable L al no ser usada en todos los archivos html, si o si tiene que estar dentro del DOMContentLoaded ??

Comment: Recordá [edit] tu pregunta cada vez que vas a agregar información relevante, ya que los comentarios son efímeros. La variable `L` está relacionada a Leaflet; ¿podrías reelaborar tu pregunta?

Comment: Claro la variable L esta relacionada, pero cómo se procede cuando tenes varios html en tu sitio? Tal vez estoy armando mal mi árbol de variables dentro del main, tal vez necesite una gobal y no local.